# Layover time vs Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas, transit-visas, layovers

My wife has an Iranian passport, and she got a green card visa in the passport. I got her a ticket from Istanbul to FCO Rome. Layover is 12 hours and then FCO to the USA.

She won’t go out of the airport since she doesn’t have a Schengen visa. But I’m wondering: she will arrive at terminal 1 and her next connecting flight is from terminal 3. Does she need a Schengen visa?

Comment: Are the two flights on the same ticket?

Comment: Yes, we got 1 ticket but it’s code share, from istanbul is Turkish airline and from Italy it’s Alitalia.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)